# Are Glassdoor reviews considered protected concerted activity under the NLRA?

Tags: united-states, labor-law

The National Labor Relations Board has recently upheld that posts on social media can be considered protected concerted activity. ([Recent Cases](https://www.nlrb.gov/rights-we-protect/protected-concerted-activity), [34-CA-012576](https://www.nlrb.gov/case/34-CA-012576))

A negative company review on Glassdoor is discussing working conditions with an attempt to improve them (see "Advice to Management").  So long as there are no false claims in the review, and there are other active employees engaging in providing reviews for the company, would this be considered protected concerted activity as well?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe it would *not* be protected?  E.g., how did the NLRB define "social media?"

Comment: There's been multiple interpretations of what constitutes "social media". The argument exists that it's disparaging activity along with employment at will... Etc. I believe it is protected, but, I'm not an expert.